# jQuery selector runs twice on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

On my website there's two file uploaders simulated by `<a>` tag.

```
    $('.drop a').click(function(){
        // Simulate a click on the file input button
        // to show the file browser dialog
        $(this).parent().find('input').click();
    });
```

Both of them have class attribute set to "drop" and ids "drop1" and "drop2".
On Firefox and Chrome after clicking the button file upload window apears. On IE it also appears, but after choosing the file it apears for the second time. I have no idea why.

```
$('#drop1 a').click(function(){
        // Simulate a click on the file input button
        // to show the file browser dialog
        $(this).parent().find('input').click();
    });

    $('#drop2 a').click(function(){
        // Simulate a click on the file input button
        // to show the file browser dialog
        $(this).parent().find('input').click();
    });
```

- this works the same way